# Zend Date giving wrong format for the CONSTANT Zend_Date::DATES

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm having a problem getting the right date format to be returned from my function.  The ZF documentation says if I use the constant "Zend_Date::DATES" or "Zend_Date::DATE_MEDIUM" it should return the date in a format `03.09.2011` for en_us locale [Zend Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.constants.html)  But I'm getting the date returned like this `Mar 9, 2011` for both of those constants.  However, if I use the "Zend_Date::DATE_SHORT" constant I get `03/09/11` which is exactly what the documentation says it should be.  So why do the other two constants give me a different format...is it some catch-all default if something is wrong?  I doubt this is a ZF bug because loads of people would have flooded them with the bug, so I'm sure I've just got something wrong, but I can't figure out what it might be and need a little help for anyone interested.

here's my function:

```
function ZEND_format_date_locale_display($str_date, $lang_LOCALE)
{
    include_once $zend_lib_path . '/Zend/Date.php';
    $date = new Zend_Date();
    $date->set($str_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');    
    $date = $date->toString(Zend_Date::DATES, $lang_LOCALE);
    return $date;
}
```

The date comes out of the mysql database like '2011-03-09' for a March 9, 2011 date.

I call the function like this:

```
ZEND_format_date_locale_display('2011-03-09', 'en_us')
```

any help or ideas are appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Zend Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.constants.html) says that "The example output below reflects localization to Europe/GMT+1 hour (e.g. Germany, Austria, France)". So if you set your locale to e.g. 'de' you should get the expected results.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I just checked the locale and it is using 'en_US' as the value.  if I change it to 'fr_FR' for french I get the same problem...any other ideas?

Comment: @Ronedog. For 'de_DE' you should get the format you want (though I relize you must use en_US). Are you sure that Zend_Date for en_US should produce 03.09.2011? Sorry, nothing else comes to my mind right now.

Comment: well...i stand corrected...i put in the hard coded line of 'de_DE' and it gave me the result i wanted.  now i need to figure out the codes for en_US and fr_FR....i thought those were the right ones.  thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: ok, according to this documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.appendix.html   'en_US' and 'fr_FR' should be supported locales and i would assume should output the date format just like it did for 'de_DE' except the month & day placing would be swapped around based on the locale.  But, when I put in 'en_US' and fr_FR I get my original error again (the output is Mar 10, 2011 instead of 03/10/2011 ...so, do you think there is a bug inside ZEND causing this?

Comment: @Ronedog. i don't know it it is a bug, though it is off course possible. Anyway, as a quick, temporary solution I would recommend refactoring your function by adding an if statement that de_DE should be used instead en_US or something in this sense.

Comment: bummer...i was hoping not to hardcode that kind of stuff into the function, but i think u r right...i'd rather finish the project. thanks for your help.

Comment: turned out not to be too much work.  i have language files and put the date format for each language file in a session variable.  now when I run the function with the zend stuff I don't use their constants, but rather i replaced the 'Zend_Date::DATES' with a $_SESSION['date_format'] based on the language preference they select.  Thanks for all your replies and for suggesting to refactor the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use PHP's inbuilt functions? 
You can use strtotime() to convert a date in any readable format into a UNIX timestamp, and then you can use date() to convert this timestamp into any format.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: well, started with zend...never really gave the php stuff a thought i'll look into it...does it work well with multiple locales?